# Failed to create voting files on disk group DATA

Tags: linux, oracle

I has install Oracle RAC 11.2.0.3 on Oracle Linux 6.6 for 2 node. When install Clusterware to step execute `root.sh` had got error below. Can you help me check how to fix that and what wrong while install Clusterware. Please ask me if you need any information.

> Failed to create voting files on disk group DATA
>   Change to configuration failed, but was successfully rolled back.
>   CRS-4000: Command Replace failed, or completed with errors.
>   Voting file add failed
>   Failed to add voting disks at /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/crs/install/crsconfig_lib.pm line 6780.
>   /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/perl/bin/perl -I/u01/app/11.2.0/grid/perl/lib -I/u01/app/11.2.0/grid/crs/install /u01/app/11.2.0/grid/crs/install/rootcrs.pl execution failed